# PHP Regular Expression. Must begin with specific word and after any number. Can't have space

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to figure it out a Regular Expression that matches. I looked at a few answers to similar questions but I couldn't figure it out the last part of it.

This is what I got, just want to make sure if it covers everything and it doesn't have false matches...

```
/^(cdn|ns|CDN|NS)([0-9])*$/
```

My goal is to match any entry that starts with cdn or ns and have 0 or more numbers (only numbers) after. It can't have any space before, in the middle or after.

I hope this is not a duplicated, I spent about an hour going through the suggested answers.

Thanks!

Comment: ...and what is the expected ending of it?

Comment: Looks good to me, though I would move the asterisk inside the parenthesis

Comment: Thanks guys. I just tested and I found a flaw. It doesn't match the space in between the begging string and the number. So this is not matching and it should:
cdn 4

Comment: Hi @jessica is for a personal project of mine, not allowing entering a string with that criteria. Thanks

Comment: No, that's fine as long as it doesn't have spaces. So this would not match "cdn4hello"... and this would match "cdn 4hello" because of the space

Comment: You want just one space or one or more spaces? This would match just one space. $regex = "~(cdn|ns) [0-9]*~i";

Comment: Hi @jessica thanks for helping. One or more spaces

Comment: Use this for one or more spaces. $regex = "~(cdn|ns) +[0-9]*~i"; Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi @jessica that works very well, the only thing is that is allowing space after the string, but I guess I can just trim it before testing! Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for one or more spaces. Good luck! :)

```
$regex = "~^(?:cdn|ns) *[0-9]*$~i";
```

Comment: Hmm... I apologize... but I'm testing the basic example and it's not working. It matches with the space "cdn 4" but if you test the basic "cdn4" or just "cdn" it doesn't match :(

Comment: @Kitara But you just said that you don't want it to match if it doesn't have spaces..."No, that's fine as long as it doesn't have spaces. So this would not match "cdn4hello"

Comment: Yes "cdn4hello" is not a match ... but "cdn4" is... that's the basic thing, that it has to start with cdn or ns and have only numbers after to be a match

Comment: Hi @jessica thanks for this. It works but it doesn't match when there are spaces, which is fine! I'll just have all spaces trimmed before applying the regex! Thanks!!